# Retrieve Devise errors from a custom SessionController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I made my own SessionController that extends Devise::SessionsController. That way it can respond to HTML, JSON, and XML depending on if the user is in the browser or using a mobile device.

If the format is HTML, I just call `super` and everything is normal. If it is JSON/XML, I want to be able to display the errors along with the 401 status code if the login did not work. Right now I have:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { super }

    if current_user
        ...
    else
       format.json { render :json => { :status => 401 } }
    end
end
```

I want to add `:errors => ???` to that hash. But how do I get the list of errors from Devise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, form errors are stored in `object.errors` (for use in a view). It seems like you might be able to pull the errors out of the `resource` object, based on the code in the Devise core SessionsController